# Detached solr cores while server restarts

Tags: solr

We are using Bitnami solr 6.2.1 with sitecore 8.1 update 3.

Every thing is just working fine in our development and qa environment. The issue is, whenever these environment gets rebooted or restarted for any reason, all cores from the solr server are detached. However all related files for these cores are still there in the file system.

Thus, every time we restarted server, we need to add all related cores back to the solr server.

Is there any way, not to loose these cores from solr while server restart.

Comment: Make sure the cores are located in the same Solr instance's folders. I think when Solr starts it looks inside a specific folder, so if the cores are not inside that folder it will not see them. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38787428/apache-solr-6-1-0-cores-being-deleted-when-solr-restart) for more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks TanerM,

You gave me the direction. All cores are at the correct location but there is one clue in your suggestion answer, mentioned in the more details link.

I have multiple cores in my solr-Installation. When i checked the core.properties, i found duplicate "name"-Attributes for few cores. I got the list of duplicate name for cores from the solr log file.

I replaced that duplicate name from the core.properties with the relevant core name and everything is working as expected. :)